# How to create a Case with conditional case ownerId

Tags: apex, rest

In apex rest, when the client wanted to create a Case record in salesforce ... if the user already existed it will create case with OwnerId = requested UserId
other wise it will create a case and queue will take care about owneship.

just important code to understand:

```
list<user> userId = [select id, name from user where username = : objectApexRestRequest.userEmail];
if(!userId.isEmpty()){
 case objLead = getCaseCreation(objectApexRestRequest, userId.id[0]);
 // and return some parameters
}

private static case getCaseCreation(wrapper obj, Id ownerId){ //supporting wrapper class

        return new case(FirstName = obj.FirstName, LastName =obj.LastName, OwnerId = ownerId,Phone = obj.Phone, Email = obj.Email,); 
}
```

Problem is : `userId.isEmpty() == null` , then it passes  "ownerId" parameter as null into getCaseCreation method. So , it will cause an error.

What is the remedy for it

1. ownerId not empty it will create case with that ownerId
2. ownerId is equal to empty it has to create the case record but ownership will be assigned to the queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something like this. Query the queue id as well and if UserId not found then pass the QueueId.

```
List<Queue> qList = [select Id from Group where Name = 'My Group' and Type = 'Queue'];
if(!userId.isEmpty()){
 case objLead = getCaseCreation(objectApexRestRequest, userId.id[0]);
 // and return some parameters
}else {
case objLead = getCaseCreation(objectApexRestRequest, qList[0].Id);
 // and return some parameters

}
```

Comment: Thushar good solution, but what if i don't want to assign queueId through apex. It has to pass OwnerId if User is existed otherwise no OwnerField in lead creation . Can we do that in this way...

Comment: @ApexCode then it will take the default running user as ownerId. Unless you have some assignment rule running in backend. Then your code would be `case c = new case(//other fields will remain here); if(ownerId != null) c.OwnerId = ownerId;`

Answer (score 0):

Then in your code, check if the `ownerId` is null. If it is, then get the queue Id instead.

```
Id case_owner_id;
try {
    case_owner_id = [SELECT
        Id,
        Name
        FROM User
        WHERE Email = :user_email
        LIMIT 1
    ];
} catch (QueryException e) {
    // didn't found the user? no problem.
    // we just assign to the queue instead
    // in the finally statement.
} finally {
    if (case_owner_id == null) {
        case_owner_id = [SELECT
            Id,
            Name
            FROM Group
            WHERE Type = 'Queue'
            AND DeveloperName = 'MySpecialCaseQueue'
        ];
    }
}
return new Case(
    OwnerId = case_owner_id,
    // create your case with the info you got...
);
```